# CORS error in PUT and DELETE methods when ASP.NET API is deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, cors

I implemented an `ASP.NET API (.NET 8)`. All endpoints works as it should when I am debugging, but when I deploy this API into my local IIS, it throws me the following error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7162/Scene' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

This error **only** happens on `HttpPut` and `HttpDelete` endpoints and, as I said, when it is deployed into my local IIS.

I have configured my CORS policies like this:

```
app.UseCors(x => x
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
.AllowCredentials());
```

If someone could help me on what could be happening, I will be very grateful.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to web.config WebDAVModule and WebDAV in publish files like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It worked! Could you explain me what is that?

Comment: Sure, It’s about the web server for example IIS ignore these type of DELETE and PUT requests, actually you got 404 response. You changed it in the config file.

Comment: @kiamehrhosseini: Thanks for responding with an explanation. That’d be useful to [edit] into your answer. Would you mind doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure app.UseCors is called before app.UseAuthorization() and after app.UseRouting() in your Startup.cs. The order in which they appear is crucial

Also, In your web.config file, you might need to add specific settings to allow all headers or the ones necessary for your application to work.

```
 <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I am having the same problem